# How am i able to change the background color of the page when the timer minutes hits at a certain target?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently making a timer/stopwatch where if the timer hits 5 minutes then I'm trying to make the background color change to for example green, and when it hits 10 minutes I want it to change to blue, etc...

Here is the code

```
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;


let interval = null;

let status = "stopped";

//Stopwatch function
function stopWatch(){

    seconds++;

    if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displaySeconds = seconds;
    }

    if(minutes < 10){
        displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayMinutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayHours = hours;
    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}


function startStop(){
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started";

    }
    else{
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped";
    }
}

//Function to reset stopwatch
function reset(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";

}

function changeColor(){
    if (seconds === 300){
        document.change.bgColor = "green";
    }
    else if (seconds === 600){
        document.change.bgColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (seconds === 900){
        document.change.bgColor = "red";
    }
}
```

As you can see i have added the function for changing the color but when I tried it, unfortunately, nothing happened and I'm trying to figure out what could be the possible error if you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: What is `document.change` supposed to be? Check your console for errors.

Comment: @Lain I have checked for errors and I have 0 found, the document.change is supposed to be for the actual background color to change and that is why I am using the "document.change" for it.

Comment: is changeColor function being called?If yes, then the answer should solve it

Comment: how do you execute the function changeColor() ?

Comment: @Rojen I believe so yes it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, `changeColor()` is never executed. To fix this invoke it at the end of `stopWatch()`.

```
function stopWatch(){
    seconds++;

    if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displaySeconds = seconds;
    }

    if(minutes < 10){
        displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayMinutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayHours = hours;
    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;

    changeColor();
}
```

Secondly, calculate the passed time in seconds by using your variables `seconds`, `minutes` and `hours`. So your new `changeColor()` function looks like this:

```
function changeColor(){
    var tSeconds = seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60);

    if (tSeconds === 300){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else if (tSeconds === 600){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (tSeconds === 900){
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q64yL0fh/3/

Comment: so is there any other suggestions instead of using the changeColor?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
```

you have set seconds to 0 if it reaches 60. So, It never reaches 300.
and also `document.change.bgColor` should be `document.body.style.backgroundColor`

I hope this solves

Comment: But that part is to function the stopwatch so if i want to change it to 300 will it not interrupt the actual maths for the time?

Comment: can u put from where function are being called?

Comment: @Tauheed Ahmad: You have to calculate back the hours and minutes to seconds in the change backgroundColor function. `var tSeconds = seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60)`. Also be aware that you only compare exact machtes of seconds (exactly 300, no more, no less). Probably should change it to >=.

Comment: @Lain Where would i apply this in the code? would it be after the seconds++; ?

Comment: Inside `changeColor()`. Instead of `seconds === x` you would have `tSeconds >= x`. Your `seconds` represents the acutal second on the clock and not the total amout of time passed in seconds. Thus like Rojen pointed out, will/should never be larger than 59.

Comment: I have changed it to                                                                                          function changeColor(){
    if  (tSeconds >= 300){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else if (tSeconds >= 600){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (tSeconds >= 900){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
} And i still have no results

Comment: You have to put `var tSeconds = seconds + (minutes * 60) + (hours * 60 * 60)` as first line of the function. Before comparing. Also put `console.log(seconds, minutes, hours)` and see what you actually get.

Comment: @Lain Still no results i tried adding it in the first line and i have still got no results when it hits 5 minutes

Comment: Do you even call it at one point? What does the log, which I told you to add, show?

Comment: Create a demo on `jsfiddle.net`. It will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `document.change.bgColor` with `document.body.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and i still have no results.

Comment: Do you ever actually call `changeColor()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.body.style.backgroundColor` instead of `document.change.bgColor`. Here is your revised code:

```
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;


let interval = null;

let status = "stopped";

//Stopwatch function
function stopWatch(){

    seconds++;

    if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displaySeconds = seconds;
    }

    if(minutes < 10){
        displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayMinutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayHours = hours;
    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}


function startStop(){
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 1000);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started";

    }
    else{
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped";
    }
}

//Function to reset stopwatch
function reset(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";

}

function changeColor(){
    if (seconds === 300){
        document.change.bgColor = "green";
    }
    else if (seconds === 600){
        document.change.bgColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (seconds === 900){
        document.change.bgColor = "red";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;


let interval = null;

let status = "stopped";

//Stopwatch function
function stopWatch(){

    seconds++;

    if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displaySeconds = seconds;
    }

    if(minutes < 10){
        displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayMinutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayHours = hours;
    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}


function startStop(){
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 10);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started";

    }
    else{
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped";
    }
}

//Function to reset stopwatch
function reset(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";

}

function changeColor(){
    if (seconds === 300){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else if (seconds === 600){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (seconds === 900){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

I just tried this suggestion and the page still does not change any color

Answer (score 0):

```
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;

let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;


let interval = null;

let status = "stopped";

//Stopwatch function
function stopWatch(){

    seconds++;

    if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displaySeconds = seconds;
    }

    if(minutes < 10){
        displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayMinutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayHours = hours;
    }

    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}


function startStop(){
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(stopWatch, 10);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started";

    }
    else{
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped";
    }
}

//Function to reset stopwatch
function reset(){
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    document.getElementById("startStop").innerHTML = "Start";

}

function changeColor(){
    if (seconds === 300){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
    else if (seconds === 600){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (seconds === 900){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

This is what i have currently and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

full code :

```js
let seconds = 0;
let minutes = 0;
let hours = 0;
let displaySeconds = 0;
let displayMinutes = 0;
let displayHours = 0;
let displayBox= document.getElementById("display");
let startStopBox = document.getElementById("startStop")
let interval = null;

let status = "stopped";
//Stopwatch function
function watch(){
    changeColor();
    seconds++;
    if(seconds / 60 === 1){
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;

        if(minutes / 60 === 1){
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    if(seconds < 10){
        displaySeconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
    }
    else{
        displaySeconds = seconds;
    }

    if(minutes < 10){
        displayMinutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayMinutes = minutes;
    }
    if(hours < 10){
        displayHours = "0" + hours.toString();
    }
    else{
        displayHours = hours;
    }
    displayBox.innerHTML = displayHours + ":" + displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds;
}

function startStop() {
    if(status === "stopped"){
        interval = window.setInterval(watch, 1000);
        startStopBox.innerHTML = "Stop";
        status = "started";

    }
    else{
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        startStopBox.innerHTML = "Start";
        status = "stopped";
    }
}

//Function to reset stopwatch
function reset(){
    console.log('number 3');
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    hours = 0;
    displayBox.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    startStopBox.innerHTML = "Start";

}

function changeColor(){
    if (seconds === 1){
        document.body.bgColor = "green";
    }
    else if (seconds === 5){
        document.body.bgColor = "yellow";
    }
    else if (seconds === 10){
        document.body.bgColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="display"></p>
    <p id="startStop"></p>
    <button onclick="stopWatch()">stopWatch</button>
    <button onclick="startStop()">startStop</button>
    <button onclick="reset()">reset</button>
    <button onclick="changeColor()">changeColor</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

I add your function from in html as I can run your functions and change function name stopWatch to watch . 
And call your function changeColor inside the watch function for running changeColor function and I change document.change.bgColor to  document.body.bgColor for change body background color if you wont change other background or style you can take help in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp).
so if you need make a file .js you have to call file from footer and next html code for running functions in your files.